# excuse me but my title label doesn't show in my button

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

```
var localizedStringSubmit = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("SUBMIT", "")
btnSubmit.TitleLabel.Text = localizedStringSubmit
```

Comment: Why are you setting localizedStringSubmit equal to itself? I think this boils down to X = Y = X;

Comment: did you get value in localizedStringSubmit

Comment: I try to locate the language according to the country @fungusanthrax

Comment: Yes, the value is correct but doesn't show @Gagan_iOS

Comment: Os this a Custom, subclassed `UIButton`? Or `UIView`? Where is `.TitleLabel` being defined?

Comment: is a subclassed from UILabel @DonMag

Comment: @M.Bernal - hmmm... sorry, I didn't notice when I commented that you are using `xamarin` - unfortunately, I don't use that, so I don't think I can offer much help.

Comment: Try to debug to see if TitleLabel is null . also could you share us the whole subclass code of btnSubmit?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your support, I solved the problem. I was using a subclass of label that did not work to generate the text that should have the button, this is what I did

` var localizedStringSubmit = NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("SUBMIT", "");

btnSubmit.SetTitle(localizedStringSubmit, UIControlState.Normal);
`